# adding css to gtk4 application

Tags: css, gtk4

I have a ui definition file as follows:

```
<object class="GtkLabel" id="view_header">
   ...
</object>
```

and css as follows:

```
#view_header { font: 1.2em bold }
```

Since the class attribute is already used to define the ObjectClass, how do I define a "css class" that I can use to select multiple view headers?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `css-classes` property of your object to set the classes that are applied to it. For example, changing your object to use a custom `some-class`:

```xml
<object class="GtkLabel" id="view_header">
  <property name="css-classes">some-class</property>
</object>
```

Then, on your `.css` file, you just define your styles as usual.

```css
#view_header { font: 1.2em bold }

.some-class {
  // whatever you want...
}

#view_header.some-class {
  // whatever you want...
}
...
```